# Macro which performs a series of operations on a given set of data

Tags: vba, excel

This macro calculates some basic figures from a given set of data. But it runs very slow probably due to me referencing the sheet again and again. Does anyone have a better idea on how to optimize this code:

```
Sub Handler_Fees()

Dim strFile, tarFile As String

Dim Source As Workbook

Dim Target As ThisWorkbook

Dim ws1 As Worksheet

Dim ThisCell, ThatCell, WhichCell As Range

Dim t As Single

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
strFile = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xlsx*), *.xlsx*", Title:="Choose the export from the inducement engine")

Workbooks.Open (strFile)

t = Timer
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("R3") = "Price per share"

Range("R4").Select
ActiveCell.Value = "=J4/F4"

Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("R4:R" & Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Set ws1 = ActiveSheet
Set Source = ActiveWorkbook
Set Target = ThisWorkbook

ThisWorkbook.Activate
Range("H2").Select


ActiveCell.Formula2R1C1 = "=INDEX('[" & Source.Name & "]" & ws1.Name & "'!R4C18:R38C18, MATCH(RC3&RC1,'[" & Source.Name & "]" & ws1.Name & "'!R4C3:R38C3 & '[" & Source.Name & "]" & ws1.Name & "'!R4C5:R38C5,0))"

Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("H2:H" & Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select


Target.ActiveSheet.Range("G1") = "Corrected Quantity"
Range("G2").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=D2/(10^E2)"

Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("G2:G" & Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select

Target.ActiveSheet.Range("H1") = "Price per share"
Target.ActiveSheet.Range("I1") = "Assessment"

Range("I2").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=G2*H2"

Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("I2:I" & Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select


Target.ActiveSheet.Range("J1") = "Portfolio commission percentage"

Range("J2").Select
ActiveCell.Formula2R1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC3,'[" & Source.Name & "]" & ws1.Name & "'!R4C3:R38C11,9,0)"

Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("J2:J" & Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select

Target.ActiveSheet.Range("K1") = "Trailer Fees"
Range("K2").Select
ActiveCell.Value = "=((I2/100)*J2)/365"

Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("K2:K" & Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select

Range("J2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("J2:J" & Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy

Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
'Selection.Value = Format(ActiveCell, "0.00")

Range("K2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("K2:K" & Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy

Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
'Selection.Value = Format(ActiveCell, "0.00")
For Each ThisCell In Range("K2:K" & Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
ThisCell.Value = Application.Round(ThisCell.Value, 2)
Next ThisCell

Range("H2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("H2:H" & Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy

Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

For Each ThatCell In Range("H2:H" & Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
ThatCell.Value = Application.Round(ThatCell.Value, 2)
Next ThatCell

For Each WhichCell In Range("I2:I" & Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
WhichCell.Value = Application.Round(WhichCell.Value, 2)
Next WhichCell

Range("A1").Select

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
MsgBox Timer - t
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you describe the objectives of the program in terms of the real-word function?  And summarise the input format?  "_A series of operations on a given set of data_" pretty much describes any program you ever write!  From the strings here, it looks like it's something to do with stock-market trading, but that's not mentioned anywhere in the description.

Answer (score 3):

A little observation:

When many variables are declared in one line it must be specified the type of each one. There are two lines in your code that doesn't accomplish this.

```
Dim strFile, tarFile As String
Dim ThisCell, ThatCell, WhichCell As Range
```

The correct is:

```
Dim strFile As String, tarFile As String
Dim ThisCell As Range, ThatCell As Range, WhichCell As Range
```

What happens if you don't do that? The variables that don't have the corresponding type are declared by default as Variant, a kind of data type more general and that occupy more memory (bytes, not much). Specifying the data type at the end of the line does not mean that all the variables listed will take that type. It's a little observation. I don't believe that is the cause of the lag in your code. If you can upload your file or a screenshot of the sheet from the data are being taken it's more easy to understand the context to help you.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of:

```
Range("R4").Select
ActiveCell.Value = "=J4/F4"
```

Avoid selecting the cells and just assign the values directly to the cells

```
Range("R4").Value = "=J4/F4"
```

You can also do the same for autofills:

```
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("R4:R" & Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
```

Becomes:

```
Range("R4").End(xlUp).Row).AutoFill Destination:=Range("R4:R" & Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

You start off with the first cell of the autofill where you're getting the data from.

Basically anything where you've got `Selection`, `Select`, `ActiveCell`, try and reference the cell itself.